# Call groovy script dynamically in Apache Camel using doTry-doCatch

Tags: groovy, apache-camel

I'm building a route which calls a groovy script whose path is dynamically computed and, if the script can't be found, defaults to a generic, static script:

```
.doTry()
.toD("language://groovy:resource:classpath:scripts/${exchangeProperty.consumerType}ResponseHandler.groovy")
.doCatch(FileNotFoundException.class)
.script().groovy("resource:classpath:scripts/defaultResponseHandler.groovy")
.end()
```

The problem is that the exchange property `consumerType` is not resolved since the uri string parameter of `toD` is evaluated using groovy and not simple.

```
    MultipleCompilationErrorsException -> startup failed:
    Script_09b4150584d9e2c979353feee06897b5.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: 'scripts/${exchangeProperty.consumerType}' @ line 1, column 20.
       resource:classpath:scripts/${exchangeProperty.consumerType}ResponseHandler.groovy
                      ^
1 error
```

How can I obtain the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error shown there, it seems Camel is not able to resolve the string you provided in the `toD()`.

By default, the expression you pass to a dynamic to is evaluated as Simple language but, as described in [To Dynamic Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.16.x/eips/toD-eip.html), you can specify other languages for the dynamic evaluation.

In your case, you are trying to evaluate the endpoint with groovy language but then you're using Simple language to substitute a piece of the name of the script.

One solution I've found (yet not the best) would be to specify the language for the interpretation of the string as simple and then use `language:groovy` to specify the endpoint that will need to be called.

You could write something like this:

```
.doTry() 
 .toD("language:simple:language://groovy:resource:classpath:scripts/${exchangeProperty.consumerType}ResponseHandler.groovy")
.doCatch(FileNotFoundException.class)
 .script().groovy("resource:classpath:scripts/defaultResponseHandler.groovy")
.end()
```

It seems to work, but I hope someone else comes up with a better solution.